# Win8 app to search a printer on a WLAN and let user select a printer and take the printout

Tags: printing, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to implement the following feature in win8 application:-

1. App detects WLAN name which is in a specific format that enables to detect building and floor
2. App shows printers that are on the same floor as the user
3. User selects printer

I know about the print contract but let user select a printer which are already added and dont allow to search and select it in WLAN as per requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, you likely cannot do this directly through the devices known by the computer. Printing in Windows Store apps uses contracts, much like accessing files not in Known Libraries or accessing Contacts. These pickers are guards meant to prevent things like Social Engineering and unauthorized access, among others.

So, what you'll likely have to do is create a custom service (such as WCF) on the network which enumerates all of the printers and acts as a mediary between the actual printing and the creation of the print document. Your app can then filter the enumeration returned by it.

Comment: It's considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an intended use case for a Windows Store App. You will NOT find the API to accomplish these tasks. There are various reasons. The core issue is that the operating system handles printers, not apps.

I hope this saves you some time.

Best of luck!